# How to start the timer in c immediately

Tags: c, linux, timer

Timer starts after the some period. 
In order for the first timer handler to get called I have to wait for a minimum of timer.it_value.tv_sec seconds.
I want my time handler to get called immediately after setitimer function.

If I set timer.it_value.tv_sec =0 , the timer stops.

I m trying to implement on and off mechanism using timers.

```
timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0; // If I do this timer stops
timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 2;
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
```

So in order to execute immediately, I have set timer.it_value.tv_usec = 1,
but it costs 1 usec delay like below.

```
timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0; 
timer.it_value.tv_usec = 1;// Here it is
timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 2;
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
```

Any other way ?

Comment: Why don't you set `it_value.tv_sec` to the wanted number of seconds, and then *explicitly* call the timer handler function? Explicitly calling the timer handler function is like the timer has elapsed.

Comment: Yeah ^^^^ why not just call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to activate the timer every two seconds except for the initial case, just set it up for two seconds but raise the signal immediately before you start the timer, something like:

```
#include <signal.h>

timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 2;
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
raise(SIGALRM);
setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
```

Raising `SIGALRM` is, after all, what `setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, ...)` will do when the timer expires.